# How to escape a symbol in Prolog using re_replace

Tags: prolog, escaping

I tried to use re_replace to replace characters in string. For example:

```
?- re_replace("_"/g, "QW", "a_b_c", Str).
Str = "aQWbQWc".
```

Then I tried to replace `_` with `\_`. The [documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=re_replace/4) says:

> Because \ is an escape character inside strings, you need to write
> "\\\\" to get a single backslash.

So I tried:

```
?- re_replace("_"/g, "\\\\_", "a_b_c", Str).
false.
```

For some reason I get `false`. What's wrong? How can I get `a\_b\_c` from `a_b_c`?

SWI Prolog version: 8.2.1.

Comment: Seems a bug, I have posted a [question in the forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/re-replace-behaviour/5231)